# Aligning image with text

Tags: beamer, graphics, align, presentations

I'm using beamer and I want to align an image (to the right) with the options to customize it's width and height and some text to the left of that image.
For example, an image of a person to the right and a summary of his work to the left.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for the `columns` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            content...
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{column}        
    \end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to put a caption with \caption{} but it didn't work. Error message says, "\caption outside float."

Comment: @Fib1123 If you want to use `\caption`, you have to place the image it in a figure environment. However for the use with beamer, I would simply place the text of your caption below the image, without using a caption.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do that  after all image appears separately with no text.

Comment: @Fib1123 Please ask a clear question with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). From your comments I can only guess what you are trying to do.